# Chrome scroll lag on initial load

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, css, scroll, parallax

Been trying to figure out exactly what is going wrong all day with a site that i'm building and I can't for the life of me figure out what is going wrong.

One of the main features of the site is parallax scrolling, which should be nice and smooth as the user scrolls down, with multiple layers animating.

Basically, whenever the site http://beta.residencyradio.com/ is loaded in Chrome (on windows) and you attempt to scroll down the page, there is a significant lag and scrolling is very jumpy.

However, if you go to the address bar, click the address and hit enter, then attempt the scroll again, and it scrolls smoothly as it should!

I'm tearing my hair out with this one, I think it is also affecting chrome on mac too, so if anyone has any idea what is going on with this, it would be a massive help and would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: after having a quick look around into this, I see this might be to do with the caching of the page perhaps, if anyone has any suggestions on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, i've found this isn't an actual problem with chrome, its actually an issue with CSS3, in particular, the rotate, so I'll be posting a separate question on that issue